Error logging in: onLoginSuccess is not a function
This is the component for Authors to Login to the Web Application
//AuthorLogin
import { Button, CircularProgress, Fade, Link, TextField, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import backgroundImage from './background.jpg';



const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#00bcd4', // Cyan color
        },
        error: {
            main: '#ff1744', // Error color
        },
    },
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
    },
    formContainer: {
        maxWidth: 400,
        width: '100%',
        padding: theme.spacing(4),
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    textField: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 200,
        padding: theme.spacing(1.5),
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
        fontWeight: 700,
        fontSize: '2.5rem',
        color: theme.palette.primary.main,
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        textAlign: 'center',
        textShadow: '2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    },
    error: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        color: theme.palette.error.main,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    link: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
}));

const AuthorLogin = ({onLoginSuccess}) => { // Accept onLoginSuccess as a prop

    const classes = useStyles();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/author/login', formData);
            console.log('Login successful:', response.data);
            // Redirect to writing portfolio upon successful login
            navigate('/writingPortfolio');
            onLoginSuccess(); // Call onLoginSuccess upon successful login
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error logging in:', error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message);
            setError(error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Fade in={true} timeout={1500}>
                <div className={classes.formContainer}>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.title}>
                            Author Login
                        </Typography>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.form}>
                            <TextField
                                type="email"
                                label="Email"
                                name="email"
                                value={formData.email}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                required
                                placeholder="Enter your email"
                            />
                            <TextField
                                type="password"
                                label="Password"
                                name="password"
                                value={formData.password}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                required
                                placeholder="Enter your password"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.button}
                                disabled={loading}
                            >
                                {loading ? <CircularProgress size={24} color="inherit" /> : 'Login'}
                            </Button>
                            {error && <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.error}>{error}</Typography>}
                        </form>
                        <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.link}>
                            Don't have an account?{' '}
                            <Link component={RouterLink} to="/AuthorRegistration">
                                Sign up
                            </Link>
                        </Typography>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </div>
            </Fade>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AuthorLogin;


This is the parent component used to help handle authors updating their details and authentication for authors to get access to respective parts of the pages
This is where the function is defined and where I want to call the function from but with no success, despite me trying everything
// ParentComponent.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AuthorDashboard from './AuthorDashboard';
import AuthorLogin from './AuthorLogin';
import AuthorProfile from './AuthorProfile';
import AuthorSettings from './AuthorSettings';

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState(null);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const handleUpdateAuthor = (updatedAuthor) => {
        setAuthor(updatedAuthor);
    };

    const handleLoginSuccess = () => {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        try {
            setError(null); // Clear any previous errors on successful login
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error handling login success:', error);
            setError('An error occurred while handling login success.');
        }
    };
    

    const handleLoginError = (errorMessage) => {
        setError(errorMessage);
    };
    
    

    return (
        <div>
            {isAuthenticated ? (
                <>
                    <AuthorSettings author={author} onUpdateAuthor={handleUpdateAuthor} />
                    <AuthorProfile author={author} />
                    <AuthorDashboard isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} authorId={author.id} />
                </>
            ) : (
                <AuthorLogin onLoginSuccess={handleLoginSuccess} onLoginError={handleLoginError} />
            )}

            {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};


export default ParentComponent;

I've tried everything I can, but I cannot get the code to work correctly

I'm testing your code to determine whether onLoginSuccess is invoked upon API success. Could you please provide more details, such as console errors and other relevant information, so I can thoroughly examine it? I'm explaining this to others, hence the request for modifications for clarity.
I am testing following method:
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            // const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/author/login', formData);
            // console.log('Login successful:', response.data);
            // // Redirect to writing portfolio upon successful login
            // navigate('/writingPortfolio');
            onLoginSuccess(); // Call onLoginSuccess upon successful login
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error logging in:', error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message);
            setError(error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

On child function
  const handleLoginSuccess = () => {
        console.log('call');
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        try {
            setError(null); // Clear any previous errors on successful login
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error handling login success:', error);
            setError('An error occurred while handling login success.');
        }
    };


These are the console errors:
isAuthenticated: undefined
AuthorDashboard.js:26 authorId: undefined
AuthorDashboard.js:30 User not authenticated. Redirecting to login page...
AuthorLogin.js:98 Login successful: {token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiO…EzOH0.sJgUOAJDZ9uN-U0z-cdRf_7DN8Vl8GOe4bMW8lOUmCA'}
AuthorLogin.js:103 Error logging in: onLoginSuccess is not a function
           I could provide the AuthorDashboard code


Please Help, I've been trying
